# Remove $ from keyword when using preg_replace

Tags: php

When a user adds $keyword into my chat application i want to remove the $ sign. $keyword is NOT a variable it is a string that contains $ to fire the keyword.

here is my code:

```
<?php

class Chat extends DB {

public function get_Messages() {

    $rows = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT user,message,TS FROM chat ORDER BY TS DESC LIMIT 50 ) sub ORDER BY TS ASC");

    foreach ($rows->results() as $row) {

        $str=$row->message;
        $stocklist = '$AAPL'; << doenst convert to link when containing $

        echo $row->TS . '<br/><strong>' .$row->user . '</strong> says: <br/>';
        echo preg_replace("/(".$stocklist.")/s","<a href='http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=$1'>$1</a>",$str) . '<br/><br/>';

    } 

}

public function send_Message($user, $message) {
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($message)) {

        $user       = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
        $message    = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

        $send = DB::getInstance()->insert('chat', array(
                'id' => null,
                'user' => $user,
                'message' => $message
            ));

        if ($send = true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

I have sorted a few bugs out, now the only issue is that the string $APPL does not convert to link. if i change $AAPL to APPL then it converts to link. I require $AAPL as a link.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you made edits since my answer. However now I don't get your question. What is `$stocklist = '$AAPL';`? So it will always have this literal value `$AAPL`?

Comment: So i am trying to only convert keywords that have $ to links. If i type AAPL without $ then it shouldnt be a link. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have modified my answer as per update in the question. Try this using preg_replace_callback():

```
$str = 'This is a $link this is not a link.';
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\$([a-z]+)/i',
    function($match) {
        $white_list = Array();// Array of all the valid links, any other match will not be replaced
        return in_array($match[1], $white_list) ? ('<a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s='.$match[1].'">'.ucfirst($match[1]).'</a>') : '$'.$match[1];
    },
    $str
);

var_dump($str); // Outputs: string(82) "This is a <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=link">Link</a> this is not a link."
```

Comment: Where do you see other quotes than single quotes: `$stocklist = '$AAPL';` ?

Comment: @Ulver Thanks mate i have managed to get this working, just one question is it possible to actually specify with links should convert? eg there is not reason to create $AJDSID since it is not a valid stock?

eg, "$AAPL|$USD"

Comment: You can specify the whitelist in the callback function of `preg_replace_callback()`. I have updated my answer to include a white list.